# Setting Event Listener to listen for two clicks before changing background colours of Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up an event listener that will swap the background colours of any 2 divs that are selected. The event listener should only swap the colours once 2 clicked are detected.

For instance, if I have 10 divs on the page, each with different colours in them, when the user clicks on the first div, nothing should happen, but once they click on another div, the event listener should swaps the background colours around.

I'm not sure if it can be done as all the divs have the same class and their starting background colour comes from an array within jquery.

```
<div class="Sample">
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
</div>
```

```
let colors = ['#ff0000', '#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffa500', '#ffc0cb', '#9b30ff', '#ffffff', '#7fffd4', '#000000']

$('.colourHolder').each(function(index, element){
  $(element).css("background-color", colors[index]);
})
```

Comment: It may be useful to know WHY you want to do this - because implementation may be different depending on the point.

Comment: I'm trying to create a small game that challenges the user to put the colours into order from dark to light. Therefore the event listener will be used to reorder the background colours. After each pair of clicks, the order of the colours will be put into an array and checked against the ordered array. They pass if they get it in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is sufficient with an `if if else` statement and then save the data in `var`s

```js
let colors = ['#ff0000', '#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffa500', '#ffc0cb', '#9b30ff', '#ffffff', '#7fffd4', '#000000']

$('.colourHolder').each(function(index, element){
  $(element).css("background-color", colors[index]);
});
var prev,
    prevcolor,
    count = 0;
function changeColor(){
  if(count==0){
    prev = $(this);
    prevcolor = prev.css("background-color")
  }else if(count==1){
    prev.css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
    $(this).css("background-color", prevcolor);
    count = -1;
  }
  count+=1;
};
$('.colourHolder').on("click", changeColor)
```

```css
.colourHolder{width: 100px;height: 100px;display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Sample">
  <div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div><div class="colourHolder"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, grab the index of the box on first click and store it. On second click, grab the index, swap the colors in the array and display their value in the array in the box.

```js
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffa500', '#ffc0cb', '#9b30ff', '#ffffff', '#7fffd4', '#000000'],
    $colourHolder = $('.colourHolder'),
    lastIdx = false,
    curIdx,
    curColor,
    lastColor;

$colourHolder.on('click',function() {
  if (lastIdx === false) {
    // get first click
    lastIdx = $(this).index();
  } else {
    // get second click
    curIdx = $(this).index();
    
    // assign cur/last colors to a var
    var curColor = colors[curIdx],
        lastColor = colors[lastIdx];
       
    // update array
    colors[lastIdx] = curColor;
    colors[curIdx] = lastColor;
    
    // update boxes on screen
    $colourHolder.eq(curIdx).css('background',lastColor);
    $colourHolder.eq(lastIdx).css('background',curColor);

    // reset click
    lastIdx = false;
  }
})
```

```css
.colourHolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Sample">
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
  <div class="colourHolder"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

There are many many ways someone might go about this.

(side note) Instead of looping through HTML - you can just create the HTML based on your array.

```
<ul class='color-list'>
  <!-- populate this -->
</ul>
```

...

```
var $colorList = $('.color-list');

var colorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'lightblue'];

for ( var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
  $colorList.append("<li class='color' style='background: " + colorArray[i] + "'>" + colorArray[i] + "</li>");
}
```

When you click the things - you'll want to store that info in an object or an array - or an array of objects.

```
var $color = $colorList.find('.color');

var currentChoices = [];

$color.on('click', function() {
  var $thisBlock = $(this);
  var thisColor = $thisBlock.css('background-color');

  // you'll also have to check and ensure the use isn't clicking the same box over and over again...

  if ( currentChoices.length < 2 ) {
    currentChoices.push(
      {
        block: $thisBlock, 
        color: thisColor,
      }
    );
  } else { // if there is already 2... empty the array maybe?
    currentChoices = [];
    currentChoices.push(
      {
        block: $thisBlock, 
        color: thisColor,
      }
    );
  }
  console.log(currentChoices);
});
```

Collect the information... and then use `.css()` to take that info and assign the styles.

You'll probably want an ID for each square etc... but here is one way to think about getting that data. You could also use data-attributes to store information on the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Lcnu8d4o

Here is a slightly more flushed out version with data-attributes to keep track of box number (i imagine you'll have to check this against the answer to the puzzle etc): https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/exf6tLhu

(should definitely be trimmed up... but hopefully, it's helpful.)